# Can't rebase a branch containing solved merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-svn, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I want to rebase my whole git history on top of a new initial commit to be able to push it to SVN.

What I don't understand is why I have to solve the same merge conflicts again. They were once solved in the original history, why can't it just take those solutions?

I have published a [minimal git-repository](https://github.com/martinsson/merge-conflict-reappears-in-rebase) to reproduce the problem :

```
git clone https://github.com/martinsson/merge-conflict-reappears-in-rebase.git
git checkout yoda
git rebase master
```

[Image of the history](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnj3bp5ui8dkud9/Screenshot%202014-10-16%2015.46.08.png?dl=0)

I am aware of git rerere, but it seems like it would have had to be activated when those conflicts were resolved in the first place. Theoretically I could activate it, solve the conflicts then use it to solve the conflicts, but in practice that it seems almost impossible to get the conflict resolving to be identical to the original one.

I am aware I could push everything to SVN, using a merge or a git graft. But that defeats the purpose which is to port the commit logs to SVN.

Comment: Johan - do you want the trees merged, or just the root parentage changed?  If the former, then I don't think `rebase` is the command you want.  `filter-branch` seems more likely.

Comment: Wasn't aware I could use filter-branch for that. However I can't make it work, what I did. `echo "8281b521 145c1aa" >> .git/info/grafts`. `git filter-branch -f --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`. `git svn dcommit`. Then I get `No changes
3147a479889ef4c88a00bd7f01cc0764930b9f90~1 == 3147a479889ef4c88a00bd7f01cc0764930b9f90
Unable to extract revision information  from commit 5bba77149399ab4d3600f642af63a43620d06fa0~1`. The merge commit is not pushed and the dcommit stops. [State b4 pushing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7sh5i3jgymbvco/Screenshot%202014-10-17%2010.07.28.png?dl=0)

Comment: [State after pushing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z22qn82vgt6r22q/Screenshot%202014-10-17%2010.15.50.png?dl=0)

Comment: So I also tried this on my real repo. `git-svn` is using rebase in order to rewrite the commits as a step in `dcommit`. So while I'm able to use `filter-branch` to put the svn commit as root, I still have to solve all the merge conflicts of the whole project to be able to push.

Answer (score 1):

The Rebase command **reapplies** all the *changes* represented by each commit on top of the target.
That is why all the conflicts seem to be reappearing.

If you want to push the current state of the project to SVN as a 'clean' (new) commit, just check it out and push all the files to SVN.
If you want to save the history then why Rebase?

Comment: I'm under the impression I can't dcommit to an empty svn repository. Hence I need to rebase on top of a single unrooted commit. 

* `johan$ git svn init svn://localhost/` 
* `johan$ git svn fetch` 
* `johan$ git svn dcommit Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history. Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.4/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 856.`